# what is the javascript equivalent for vbscript TypeName?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have to convert following function to javascript,

```
Sub document_onkeydown()
    If window.event.keyCode = 27 Then
        window.event.ReturnValue = false
    ElseIf window.event.keyCode = 13 Then
        If TypeName(window.event.srcElement) = "HTMLInputElement" Or TypeName(window.event.srcElement) = "HTMLSelectElement" Then
            If window.event.srcElement.name <> "QuickSearch" Then
                Call butSearch_OnClick
            End If
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me to convert following points,

```
 window.event.ReturnValue = false
 TypeName(window.event.srcElement) = "HTMLInputElement"
 window.event.srcElement.name <> "QuickSearch"
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ 1 ]**     `window.event.ReturnValue = false` is similar to `return false` in Javascript. 
It means returning from function when you have nothing to do in particular case.

**[ 2 ]**  `event.srcElement` points to the objects from which the event is generated.

That is Similar to `event.currentTarget` in Javascript. And the `TypeName()` retuns the type of that object, similar to `typeof()` in Javasript.

**[ 3 ]**    `event.srcElement.name` returns the `name` attribute of the object from which the event occured.

```
  function document_keyDown(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 27){
            return false;
        }
       else if(event.keyCode === 13){
       {
         if((event.currentTarget.tagName) === "TEXT" || (event.currentTarget.tagName) === "SELECT"){
            if(event.currentTarget.name === "QuickSearch"){

                btnSearch_onClick();
            }
         }
       }
    }
```